# How to add new keywords to RSyntaxTextArea

Tags: java, swing, rsyntaxtextarea

I am using RSyntaxTextArea in my swing application. I want to create an editor for Gherkin language. How can I add new keywords to extend the language support.

Comment: It's described on the homepage. Here is the [link](https://github.com/bobbylight/RSyntaxTextArea/wiki/Adding-Syntax-Highlighting-for-a-new-Language).

Comment: Have you implemented this or got any other solutions